# JavaScript event-handling (propagation/bubbling)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener, propagation

I've added an event listener to my document, that is listening on `keydown`. When certain shortcuts, i.e. `CTRL+s`, is hit, I want something to happen.
The problem is that an event is created everytime a key is pressed down, and when the right combination of keys is pressed down ALL the events that are saved up are fired at once.

Example:
I have a textbox that the user can write into. Every time they press a key an event is saved.
If they write `abc` into the textbox, then I have three events; `a`, `ab` and `abc`.
I only want the last event to be fired, not the first two.
The reason this happens, as far as I know, is because of propagation (earlier called bubbling).

What can I do to only fire the last event in the `bubble`?

My code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {

        if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === "s") {

            var isBtnDisabled = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-none align-middle mb-5").item(0).firstChild.disabled;

            if (!isBtnDisabled)
                Save();

            event.preventDefault();
        }

    }, false
    );
}, [signature]);
```

Comment: @Yousaf I'm making custom keyboard shortcuts, so isn't "keydown" the only event I can use in that scenario?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: What is `signature` in this case ? Because every time it changes, a new event listener is added to the window.

Comment: It would help if you had a self-contained example, and steps for replicating the problem. The only problem I can see is that if someone held ctrl and pressed 's' and then e.g. 'd' at the same time, then the event would fire twice. But I'm not sure if that's the problem you're talking about.